# How to Show ContextMenuStrip Above the Mouse Postion?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying make a contextMenuStrip with Notify Icon, But I can't put the location of this Context above the mouse Position. it's show at same position mouse

[Context menu strip position Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqifU.jpg)

```
private void ntfy2_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        contextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y); //Show at Postion Mouse
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something like `contextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y - 20);`  or `contextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y - contextMenuStrip1.Height / 2);`

Comment: Oke But contextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y - contextMenuStrip1.Height);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this code help you?

```
private void ntfy2_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
                var relativeClickedPosition = e.Location;
        var screenClickedPosition = (sender as Control).PointToScreen(relativeClickedPosition);
        contextMenuStrip1.Show(screenClickedPosition);
    }
}
```

@DuckFterminal if my post helped you enough, please click on bird of acceptance, ok? :)